# No se puede guardar en una bd el contenido de DropDownList con Entity framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, razor, entity-framework-6

Estoy usando Entity framework para persistencia de datos, quiero guardar un id (el campo es del tipo identity), un nombre y el sexo de la persona, pero al presionar en guardar, me tira una excepción

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.
Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.

Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Error de código fuente:


Línea 25:             {
Línea 26:                 db.Student.Add(st);
Línea 27:                 db.SaveChanges();
Línea 28: 
Línea 29:                 return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


Archivo de origen: C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\practicando\pruebas\Pruebas\Lista\Controllers\HomeController.cs    Línea: 27
```

y no puedo seguir. que está pasando?

Controlador:

```
using Lista.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Lista.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        private pruebaEntities db = new pruebaEntities();


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Student st)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Student.Add(st);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(st);
        }
    }
}
```

Modelo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Lista.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [Required]
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Gender StudentGender { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Gender
    {
        Male,
        Female
    }
}

Vista:

@using Lista.Models



@{
    Layout = null;
}



@using (Html.BeginForm("CrearCliente"))
{
    Nombre: <br />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" />
@Html.DropDownList("StudentGender",
                    new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Gender))),
                    "Select Gender",
                    new { @class = "form-control" })
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />   
}
```

no pongo en la vista @model porque o sino no me toma el enum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi debe funcionar:

Controller:

```
// GET: Home
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var sudent = new Student();

    var items = new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Male", Value = "Male"},
        new SelectListItem {Text = "Female", Value = "Female"},
    };

    ViewData["Genders"] = items;

    return View(student);
}
```

Vista:

```
@model Student
@using (Html.BeginForm("CrearCliente"))
{
    Nombre: <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName)
    @Html.DropDownList("StudentGender", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["Genders"], "Select Gender", new { @class = "form-control" })
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" />   
}
```